# jQuery switch-case not working, syntax issue?

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

Why is this switch-case not working? I've tried every possible syntax, but it is just not working. Or is a switch-case the wrong method in this case?

```
jQuery('#main input').blur(function() {
    switch(jQuery(this).attr('name') {
        case 'email':
            jQuery(this).val('That's you e-Mail adress.');
            break;
        case 'nickname':
            jQuery(this).val('That's your nickname.');
            break;
    }
});
```

Please note: I am using jQuery in non conflict mode, that's why I use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: You're missing a `)`. Use a tool like JSLint or JSHint to find problems like this.

Comment: Backticks (`) should be used for inline code. If you want to post multiple lines, please highlight the code and then click the curly braces button. It'll format it for easier reading.

Comment: Thank you, will do it like that in the future.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Sven! If you see an answer below that helps you, you should upvote it. Don't forget to *accept* the answer (if any) that best answers your question by clicking the large checkmark to the left of that question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in here:

```
switch(jQuery(this).attr('name') {
```

Missing a closing parenthesis. Should be:

```
switch(jQuery(this).attr('name')) {
```

You should escape the quote in this string:

```
jQuery(this).val('That's you e-Mail adress.');
```

Like this:

```
jQuery(this).val('That\'s you e-Mail adress.');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two types of errors:

1. You are missing a parenthesis `)` closing around the `switch` parameter.
2. You are not escaping your apostrophes (`'`) in the word "that's".

**Corrected Code:**

```
jQuery('#main input').blur(function() {
    switch(jQuery(this).attr('name')) { // Added a )
        case 'email':
            jQuery(this).val('That\'s you e-Mail adress.'); // Escaped the '
            break;
        case 'nickname':
            jQuery(this).val('That\'s your nickname.'); // Escaped the '
            break;
    }
});
```

***Update:***

If you are unfamiliar with escaping strings in JavaScript (such as with the word `That's` above), take a look at this Stack Overflow question: [Escaping Strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770523/escaping-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Using many `'` in the same line seems to mess your syntax. change as below,

```
jQuery('#main input').blur(function() {
    switch(jQuery(this).attr('name')) {  // <-- fix 1: added closing )
        case 'email':
            jQuery(this).val("That's you e-Mail adress."); // <-- fix 2: quotes 
        break;
        case 'nickname':
            jQuery(this).val("That's your nickname.");  // <-- fix 3: quotes 
            break;
    }
});
```