# My title tags are breaking up due to the ' and " from the string, how do i fix in that in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code in my javascript (its jquery)

```
$('#myobject').append("<img width='225' title='"+addslashes(post.title)+"' src='"+urlvisual+"' />");
```

the addslashes function was pulled from another post on here about escaping quotes

```
function addslashes( str ) {
    return (str+'').replace(/([\\"'])/g, "\\$1").replace(/\0/g, "\\0");
}
```

but the result is still breaking the title attribute, any suggestions?

Comment: Looks fine, but what the heck is that `replace(/\0/g, "\\0")`?

Comment: Why not use `preg_replace`?

Comment: ummmm, not sure. here is the post i found it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770523/escaping-strings-in-javascript and here is the blog post regarding that function http://phpjs.org/functions/addslashes/

Comment: HTML does not understand backslash-escaped quotes (or any backlash-escaped character) because the backslash is not an escape character in HTML.

Comment: *related* [How to properly escape quotes inside html attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since we're using jQuery anyway, we could use their element-building syntax:

```
$('<img/>', {
    width: 255,
    title: post.title,
    src: urlvisual
}).appendTo('#myobject');
```

Cleaner code, and no escaping necessary :)

Comment: awesome, that worked perfectly. So many little jquery things i still need to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to escape the string using HTML Entities instead of backslashes.

Double quotes: `" => &quot;`

Single quote: `' => &#39;`

Answer (score 0):

This function should work correctly:

```
function addslashes( str ) {
    return (str+'').replace(/'/g, "\\'");
}
```