# How do I insert quotes in anchor tag?

Tags: string, node.js, anchor, quotes

How can I insert quotes in a string, anchor tag? I am adding link using tag in my application of node.js. It is not accepting.

How to overcome that? And what is the reason it doesn't accept that?

```
"<A HREF="index.html">";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping Strings in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770523/escaping-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two methods are there

### First method

`var s = '<A HREF="index.html">';`

### Second Method

escape quotes in string literals :

`var s = "<A HREF=\"index.html\">";`

Answer (score 1):

You can escape quotes in [string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals) :

```
var s = "<A HREF=\"index.html\">";
```