# Unexpected Token while Parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, json

This is fraustating me for 5 hours and now i have to finally ask this question.

I am trying to parse JSON using Javascript, but i don't know why i am getting this error on Console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (…)
(anonymous function) @ VM382:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ 
VM251:904InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM251:837InjectedScript.evaluate 
@VM251:693
```

JSON : http://pastebin.com/DddXQj6d

JS Code:

```
var json=**big json**;
var obj=JSON.parse(json);
```

Tried:

`JSON.stringify(json);`

`json= "'" + json+ "'";`

Loading JSON from URL

Comment: “big json” is useless for us to debug the problem.

Comment: Obviosly your JSON data is not correctly formatted

Comment: Try to validate if your JSON is correct, e.g. on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @AbdullaChozhimadathil Sorry, i had forgotten that

Comment: @Xufox Sorry, i had forgotten that. Added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and the Pastebin that you posted, the JSON is invalid, mostly due to the use of `\'`. Once you replace all of them by `'`, it should work normally.

In your original JSON file there are probably going to be some occurrences of `\\'`. As a string they become `\'`.

If you’re using Linux, a simple

```bash
sed -i "s/\\\\\\\'/\'/g" yourJSONFile.json
```

on your file fixes everything.

JSONLint says “Valid JSON” then.

You can also try

```
JSON.parse(json.replace(/\\'/,'\''));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303617/unable-to-parse-json-data-that-includes-a-single-quote