# Protractor: find a text in a page

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

I've created this step definition to check if a given text exists in a web page. The code works properly but sometimes, expecially when I look for a long text, I get an error even if the text exists in the page.

The code is this:

```
this.Then(/^The text "([^"]*)" exists in page$/, function(myText, callback){

    browser.sleep(10000);

    var selectedElement = element(by.xpath("//*[. = '" + myText + "']"));

    expect(selectedElement.isPresent()).to.eventually.equal(true, "This text is not present in page").and.notify(callback);    

  });
```

Basically I do three things:

1. I wait 10 seconds to be sure that all elements of the DOM have been loaded.
2. I seach for an element(div, p, label or whatever) thet contains the text I'm looking for.
3. I check if the element is present oterwise I get an error.

Can you tell me if there is a better way to do this? It's correct to use browser.sleep() at the beginning of a step definition to wait for the DOM loading?

**IMPORTANT: I'm not using Angularjs**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is because you are using a strict text match, but there could be extra spaces or newlines around a desired text. You can try with [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) if this is applicable:

```
element(by.xpath("//*[contains(., '" + myText + "')]"));
```

Or, with [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space):

```
element(by.xpath("//*[text()[normalize-space() = '" + myText + "']]"));
```

As a side note, using `browser.sleep()` to wait for a page to load is not quite reliable and should be avoided. There is a better way - [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) and [Expected Conditions](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions).

Comment: Ok, I think that I have problem with special characters. If my page contains the text "My brother O'Brian" and I search this text I can find nothing. Do you know how to avoid this problem?? I've tried to escape the "'" but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Ema.jar yeah, you need to escape the quotes in your `myText` variable, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770523/escaping-strings-in-javascript.