# Escape quotes in string

Tags: javascript, string

I have an event that when triggered call a function like the following:

```
<a href="javascript:fav.delete(\''+addslashes(value.title)+'\')">
```

the function receive the string title as parameter and all works fine but when quotes are inside the string.

I used the function from other topic: [Escaping String in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770523/escaping-strings-in-javascript)

But the following error arises in console when click on the link:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>
> fav.delete('Y-Splitter 1/2\

I think the first occurence of the quote in string close href attribute.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: You solve this at the PHP level, not the JavaScript/HTML level. (I see you're using PHP from `addslashes`.)

Comment: Maybe you need set title like "`addslashes` equivalent on javascript"

Comment: This whole question is ill-fated. You should not be using `javascript:` hrefs in the first place. There are far better alternatives than that, your time would be well-spent to research what HTML5 can do for you (data-attributes come to mind) instead of trying to put lipstick on this pig.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I use this function: function addslashes(str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0')
}

Comment: @Apalabrados: You need to make that clear in the question itself (use the "edit" link). Sepaately, `<a href="javascript:fav.delete(\''+addslashes(value.title)+'\')">` is invalid. Consider what the JavaScript part of that looks like: `fav.delete(\''+addslashes(value.title)+'\'`. Clicking it will give you a syntax error.

Comment: @Apalabrados: The question is nonsense until/unless you correct that. There's no need, whatsoever, to escape `value.title` where you're showing you are escaping it. So clearly, more context is required (including addressing the syntax error above). If you've fetched the value via ajax as you've said in some comments, and you're referring to a property (`value.title`) in the `onclick`, there is zero escaping of `"`, `'`, or backslash required.

Answer (score 1):

You uses PHP with HTML and you question is about Javascript and HTML.

**Solution in HTML + PHP:**

```
<a href="javascript:fav.delete('<?php echo addslashes($valueTitle); ?>')">
```

> `$valueTitle` don't exists, so you need set it to use.

**Maybe you need use `addslashes` equivalent in javascript:**

```
function addslashes(str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0')
}
```

**Use like:**

```
<a href="javascript:fav.delete(addslashes(value.title))">...</a>
```

**Full Example([try here](https://jsfiddle.net/hthxLnkq/)):**

```js
function addslashes(str) {
  return (str + '').replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0');
};

var fav = {
  'delete': function(str) {
    alert('Escape string :' + str);
  }
};

var value = {
  title: "You can't touch it!"
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="fav.delete(addslashes(value.title))">Click here</a>
```

> You don't need apply single or double quotes when you use a function over another function like `fv.delete(addslashes(...))`.

Comment: I fetch content via Ajax and as I mentioned, I use the javascript addslashes function.

Comment: @OlafErlandsen Weil, since the OP isn't tagged as php, how in the world is someone supposed to know that? addslashes() could certainly be a user-defined function in JavaScript. I hope you didn't down vote for that!

Comment: I update my answer with a example. `addslashes` don't exists on `javascript`, but you can create a equivalent.

Comment: Your JavaScript example at the end (both here and on jsFiddle) alerts `Escape string :You can\'t touch it!` That backslash is out of place.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i know, but @apalabrados want use `addslashes` and it apply backslashes.

Comment: @OlafErlandsen: The OP is clearly very confused, as `value.title` requires no escaping at all where the OP is trying to do escaping.

Answer (score -1):

I'd go with this:

```
<a href="javascript:{var v= addslashes(value.title);fav.delete(v)}">
```

this way you pass a variable inside your call instead of rendering the string in place which causes a browser to stop at first double quotes inside that string.

Comment: I fetch info via Ajax