# Retain Special Characters In A String (Without Breaks)

Tags: javascript

It's hard to describe this question in the title, as an example will make sense of what I'm trying to do.

I have a JS object that I want to add to:

```
jsTestObj = [ ]
```

On each call to strings of data, I want to add a key and a value pair:

```
var pushTestObj = { };
pushTestObj["myKey"] = "MyName";
pushTestObj["myValue"] = "I call myself "Joe""; // these strings may have apostrophes, quotes, or even comments that are legit
jsTestObj.push(pushTestObj);
```

I need to retain all quotes or parenthesis in these fields (and comments, which are also possible and match JS comments).  In a sense, I am looking for a possible function (method) that simply wraps the string like:

```
pushTestObj["myValue"] = wrapStringMethodToRetainCharacters(I call myself "Joe");
```

Where JS will know it's a string in the value "myValue" and retain the quotes, apostrophes and comments, while still storing it in a string.

Escape Characters

This will work for quotes and apostrophes; what about comments.  For example:

```
var pushTestObj = { };
    pushTestObj["myKey"] = "MyName";
    pushTestObj["myValue"] = "/* He's "different" */ Sometimes David; // these strings may have apostrophes, quotes, or even comments that are legit
    jsTestObj.push(pushTestObj);
```

Comment: `pushTestObj["myValue"] = "I call myself "Joe"";` That's a syntax error, not more, not less - you have to escape the `"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping Strings in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770523/escaping-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: @Mistalis it is a duplicate, the problem is OP didn't even know that he/she is looking for `escape characters`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for escaping:

```
pushTestObj["myValue"] = "I call myself \"Joe\""; // these strings may have apostrophes or single quotes that are legit

pushTestObj["myValue"] = "/* He's \"different\" */ Sometimes David"; // these strings may have apostrophes, quotes, or even comments that are legit
```

A string can contain apostrophes or single quotes, no problem there. However you cannot type them in a string literal without escaping.

Comments have no special meaning inside a string.

It really helps if you get an texteditor with syntax highlighting, as it will quickly show you where a string starts and ends.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain special characters just escape them with a `\`.

Here is an example:

```
pushTestObj['myValue'] = 'I call myself \"Joe\"';
```

Special characters always need to be escaped.
Escaped characters will be put into a string as they are.

Just a side note your code as it is shouldn't be able to be run without a syntax error.