# Appending HTML strings into Iframe causing syntax errors, what is the correct way to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, append

**What I am doing:**

I am storing (MySQL) formatted text that is structured like this:

```
I'm Robert (I'm = I am)<br>You're in France (You're = You are)<br><br><strong></strong><span class="st">?</span> <b>I</b>'m Robert  <br>? Am Robert <del> <br></del><br>? <b>You</b>'re Robert <br>? Are Robert  <br><br>I'm = I am<br>You're = ___ ___?<br><br><br><br>
```

I am trying to retrieve this string from the database an then append it into a WYSIWYG editor like this.

```
function enableEditMode(){
            card_content.document.designMode = 'On';
            $('iframe[name=card_content]').contents().find('body').append("I'm Robert (I'm = I am)<br>You're in France (You're = You are)<br><br><strong></strong><span class="st">?</span> <b>I</b>'m Robert  <br>? Am Robert <del> <br></del><br>? <b>You</b>'re Robert <br>? Are Robert  <br><br>I'm = I am<br>You're = ___ ___?<br><br><br><br>");
}
```

I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I assume this is because of the "" quotes causing issues.

**Question:**

How do I go about appending HTML into the DOM without encuring syntax errors like this?

Comment: Classic quotes issue

Comment: Is there a function to excape quotes? e.g. \"foo\"?

Comment: You need to replace `"` in the string with `\"` so that its escaped. Exactly how you do that will depend on the server language you're using to get data from your SQL database

Comment: php `addslashes()`? Going to try that now.

Comment: you should use &quot;

Comment: @REDEVI_ that won't work in this case as the quotes are within an attribute, not part of the HTML content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to escape single quote or double quotes:

```
function addslashes( str ) {
    return (str + '').replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0');
}
```

from: [Escaping Strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770523/escaping-strings-in-javascript)

Or you escape the string in server side and return the escaped string.
Therefore, the result should be like this:

```
"this is a test, isn\'t it great! <span class=\"test\">Test</span>"
```

Comment: Cool, serverside worked for me... I was using PHP so I just wrapped my HTML in `addslashes()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
class="st"
```

by

```
class='st'
```

should do the trick. I dont see more quote conflicts.