# What's a fast, straight-forward "find any of these strings in this text" for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, search, full-text-search

What's the best method to find any of a list of substrings in a specific string?

This works, but can't be right.

```
var searchEngines = [
    new RegExp("www.google."),
    new RegExp("www.yahoo."),
    new RegExp("search.yahoo."),
    new RegExp("www.bing.")
  ];

function isSearchEngine(url){
  for (let i=0,len=searchEngines.length; i < len; i++){
    if (searchEngines[i].exec(url)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Anything to speed this up, really...

[Edit:] After rooting around I found this:

```
var searchEngines = [
      "www\.google\.",
      "www\.yahoo\.",
      "search\.yahoo\.",
      "www\.bing\.",
      "duckduckgo\."
    ].join('|');

    if (excludeSearch) {
      read = ! (new RegExp(searchEngines, 'gi')).test(keyword);
    }

// After the Map object was released in HTML5 I had this at my disposal as well
const imageExtensions = new Map();
  ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'jif', 'jfif', 'gif', 'tif', 'tiff', 'png', 'pdf', 'jp2', 'jpx', 'j2k', 'j2c', 'fpx', 'pcd'].forEach(function(e) {
    imageExtensions.set(e,true);
  });
```

Comment: How slow can that possibly be? There aren't that many search engines.

Comment: You chould combine all of those partial urls into a single regex and just do one regex.exec()

Comment: How do I turn "www.google.", "www.yahoo.", etc. into versions with the backslashes without wasting too much time?

/www\.google\.|www\.yahoo\.|search\.yahoo\.|www\.bing\./i.test(url)

Comment: If the list of substrings remains constant over some time, go with e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Try a single regex using the `|` character for alternative values.  Now instead of looping through an array, you can simply return a single regex test.

```
function isSearchEngine(url){
  return /www\.google\.|www\.yahoo\.|search\.yahoo\.|www\.bing\./i.test(url);
}
```

If your match strings are in an array, try something like this:

```js
    function isSearchEngine2(url, array){
      var fullRegString = array.join("|");//add regex escape characters here if necessary
      return new RegExp(fullRegString).test(url);
    }

    //array of strings we want to match -- ideally add escape characters to these if necessary
    var searchEngines = [
      "www.google.",
      "www.yahoo.",
      "search.yahoo.",
      "www.bing."
    ];

    console.log(isSearchEngine2('www.google.com', searchEngines));//true -correct
    console.log(isSearchEngine2('abcdefg', searchEngines));//false - correct
    console.log(isSearchEngine2('wwwAgoogleAcom', searchEngines));//true -incorrect mis-match because of '.' matching all
```

Comment: I thought I tried that, but maybe I got my slashes all topsy turvy.

But the real question is that those aren't the only choices which can be edited such that I need to OR | that list dynamically.

Nevermind. Got it figured out I'm sure. Just new to /regex/ stuff.

Comment: But now I'm seeing the \. and don't know how to make such dynamic replacements fast.

Comment: So the `.` character in a regular expression matches every character, so technically, it would work without adding the escaping \ character in front.  In that case, it would also match the value `wwwCgoogleC` (or any other character in place of C).  That may not be a problem, but it's basically an extra possible mis-match you might encounter in the future.  To replace all escapable characters, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/770533/711674) would work but it's probably not all that efficient

Answer (score 0):

Here is something a little more generic. This will return the string you pass in if it is found in the string you are searching against.

```js
function findIn (str, here) {
    let location = here.indexOf(str),
    found = here.slice(location, location + str.length);
    if (found) {
        return found;
    } else {
        return `Sorry but I cannot find ${str}`;
    }
}

/** examples
console.log(findIn('hoo', "www.yahoo.com/news/some-archive/2103547001450"));

console.log(findIn('www', "www.yahoo.com/news/some-archive/2103547001450"));

console.log(findIn('news', "www.yahoo.com/news/some-archive/2103547001450"));

console.log(findIn('arch', "www.yahoo.com/news/some-archive/2103547001450"));
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting a simple true/false from the url, or are you expecting to find multiple `searchEngines` in one string? I assume it's the former, as urls don't really contain multiple addresses....

Generally, `String.indexOf()` has the best performance for matching characters. Here's a [benchmark](http://jsbench.github.io/#c429a22c680ce74580b6aa336030d4f6) I did a while back on various string parsing methods. The benchmark itself is set up to test if multiple words are **all** present instead of one instance, so `RegExp.test()` takes the cake there, but performance suffers HARD when the result is `false`. `String.indexOf()` was by far the most reliable for parsing true/false matches and **easily** the most performant when testing one string for one single value (don't have the benchmark for that, sorry);

However, you're doing this in a loop to test for multiple things. As you can see on the benchmark, `RegExp.test()` is the most performant on successes. If we can assume most of the urls you're passing to the function contain one of those urls, I would recommend using that:

```
var searchEngines = [
    "www.google.",
    "www.yahoo.",
    "search.yahoo.",
    "www.bing."
  ];

function isSearchEngine(url){
  let regex = new RegExp(searchEngines.join('|'), 'gi');
  return regex.test(url); // returns true/false
}
```