# Search a string for words in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not seeing the error in my ways...

I am trying to search a string with keywords from an array and I just keep coming up with no results, please help me see what I am doing wrong here.

```js
    var stringArray = ["Trans", "Diode", "Label"];
    var str = "Label, SpotChem Pipettes Oversticker";
    var a = (stringArray.indexOf(str) > -1);
    var b = (str.indexOf(stringArray) > -1);

    console.log("a: " + a + " b: " + b);

    //even using jquery: $.inArray(str, stringArray) returns -1
```

```
...
```

If needed you can see this code in a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/yw1nt24r/)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169545/whats-a-fast-straight-forward-find-any-of-these-strings-in-this-text-for-jav#comment75398388_44169545

Comment: You checking if any element in the array has the value of `"Label, SpotChem Pipettes Oversticker"`, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare each word of the array to the string in question. You can use `Array.some`

```
var containsKeyWords = stringArray.some(word => str.indexOf(word) > -1);
```