# Construct an escaped string

Tags: javascript, string

I am looking for an alternative api in javascript for the [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) in java.

Basically it should be able to convert

input string:

> He didn't say, "Stop!"

output string:

> He didn't say, \"Stop!\"

Can we do the same using any underscore or any other util functions?

In underscore`s escape api,

> var a = '"test"';
>   _.escape(a)

returns

```
"&quot;test&quot;"
```

But I wanted in the format `\"test\"'`

Comment: Check out `JSON.stringify`

Comment: So basically all you want to do is _replace_ `"` with `\"` ...?

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify`?

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify('Hello "world"').slice(1, -1));
```

Comment: Hmm already an answer for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22837870/6730571), but hey, this one is runnable :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace `"` with `\"`, you can do this:

```js
var s = "He didn't say, \"Stop!\"";
console.log(s.replace(/"/g, '\\\"'));
```

If you want to escape other characters too, you can do something like this:

```js
var s = "He didn't say, \"Stop!\"";
console.log(s.replace(/("|'|\\)/g, '\\\$1'));
```

Both examples are using RegExp replace, just different regular expressions used.