# String Replace in a form hidden field - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have song titles that I am placing - ANY song that has an apostrophe breaks the the code - For example, when I try to ad "That's Alright", it registers as "That" because the ' breaks. Here is the isolated line of code. Can someone recommend a fix that will replace the ' with \'   ?

```
"<input type='hidden' name='title' value='"+val.sources[0].title+"'>"+
```

tried a variation of code from [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/)

```
var str = "Visit Microsoft!";
var res = str.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
```

But I believe the syntax was off...

```
"<input type='hidden' name='title' value='"+val.sources[0].title+"'>"+
```

I want the hidden field value to not break at the '

```
<?php if($playlist!='fav' && $membership == '2'){ // REMOVED $list ?>
            "<form id='addFavorite' action='process_fav_add_pro_preview.php?p=<?php echo $playlist; ?>' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='favid' value='"+val.sources[0].track_id+"'>"
            +
            "<input type='hidden' name='mediatype' value='"+val.sources[0].media+"'>"+
            "<input type='hidden' name='title' value='"+val.sources[0].title+"'>"+
            "<input type='hidden' name='artist' value='"+val.sources[0].artist+"'>"+
            "<input type='hidden' name='source_url' value='"+val.sources[0].src+"'>"+
            "<input type='hidden' name='credits' value='"+val.sources[0].credits+"'>"+
            "<input type='hidden' name='user' value='<?php echo $id; ?>'>"+
            "<input type='hidden' name='playlists' value='<?php echo $playlist; ?>'>"+
            "<button class='playlist-favorite' id='sub'><i class='fa fa-heart faa-flash animated-hover' style='color:#ff4444'></i></button>"+
            "</form>"
            +
            <? } ?>
```

Comment: Can you please put your code with more details?

Comment: Some more JS code would help understand.  The first line makes little sense.  Is it a part of a JS variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping Strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770523/escaping-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: Why are you putting single inverted commas and then double inverted commas? double inverted commas only should suffice `value="+val.sources[0].title+"`. I think the single inverted commas you put is breaking the value after apostrophe

Comment: I am mixing because I am combining it with html and they are requiring the opposite  marks?

Answer (score 0):

To accept the string that has apostrophe or single quote in it, you can use the following method:

```
function escapeRegExp(text) {
  return text.replace(/[']/g, '\\$&');
}
```

This is a variation of the following method:

```
function escapeRegExp(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,'\\^$|#]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

Referenced from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript) question at Stack Overflow.

If you pass the value as `escapeRegExp("That's alright")`, then it becomes `That\'s alright`

**UPDATE:**
Here is what you can try to do:

```js
$("input[name='title']").each(function(){
 var text = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(escapeRegExp(text));
});

function escapeRegExp(text) {
  return text.replace(/[']/g, '\\$&');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='title' value="That's alright">
```

Here I have just changed the type to `text` so that the output is readable, but if you change it back to `hidden` again, the code will work.

Comment: I edited the post and added the entire code block... I understand what you have posted but how do I implement it within the context of my code block?

Comment: @Davo Can you please point to the field, where you are adding `That's alright`, because your naming conventions are a bit confusing with the context of the question.

Comment: +val.sources[0].title+

Comment: Are you suggesting: "<input type='hidden' name='title' value='"+escapeRegExp(val.sources[0].title)+"'>"+

Comment: @Davo Yes, let me try to explain it by editing my answer

Comment: For the record, I tried that and it "breaks the code" - I am sure it is my syntax

Comment: @Davo, there is something wrong with the php tags in your code, please check that.

Comment: I see how it works but I have placed it above, below and inside my code block - and it doesmt work as yours - I am sure it about the exact placement - My result upon submissions shows "escapeRegExp(That"

Comment: Can I not place it directly in the line of code? I know php allows you to place it directly in a single line, such as: $title = str_replace("'","\'",$title); --- does JS allow such?