# Print backslash(\) at the end of the string

Tags: javascript, php

I want to print the string containing backslash at the end.

```
echo "test\";
echo "test\\";
```

I expect the o/p like.

```
test\
test\\
```

But in first case i am getting

```
Syntax error, unexpected end of file
```

In second case i am getting below result.

```
test\
```

Please help me to achieve the expected o/p.
Thank you

Comment: Backslash is a control character, so you need to escape it twice \\ to specify a single literal backslash.  This question must be a duplicate of something else.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is the "escaping-character". This means that the special characters (like ";:....) will be interpreted as a usual *string*.

```
echo "hello" // -> hello
echo "hello\"" // -> hello"
echo "hello\\" // -> hello\
```

You can read more here: [Escaping Strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770523/escaping-strings-in-javascript)